# unknown RR type 'CAA' - named-checkzone

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl-certificate, bind, dns-zone

I recently updated CAA records for my domain. But when I do check the zone using the command

```
named-checkzone <domain.com> <domain.com>
```

I get the error,

```
domain.com:43: unknown RR type 'CAA'
domain.com:44: unknown RR type 'CAA'
zone domain.com/IN: loading from master file domain.com failed: unknown class/type
zone domain.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.

named-checkzone -v
9.9.2-P1

CentOS release 5.3
```

What can be done to eradicate the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CAA` support was not added to BIND [until version 9.9.6](https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-01210/0/BIND-9.9.6-Release-Notes.html). If you are sure these records were working before, please make sure you are using the same checkzone binary that is packaged with your running nameserver software.